# pyramid security authenticating request

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm using pyramid authentication and here is my below code to remember the request and see if the same user is authenticated.

```
from pyramid.view import forbidden_view_config
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound, HTTPSeeOther
from pyramid.security import NO_PERMISSION_REQUIRED, Everyone, remember, authenticated_userid, unauthenticated_userid

from .oauth import OAuth
from .utils import redirect_path
from pyramid.view import (
    view_config,

    )
import requests
import logging
import json

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@view_config(route_name='login')
def login(request):

    print('login **** start')

    sm_user = request.headers.get('sm_user')
    userid = request.cookies.get('userid')

    print('sm_user - {0}'.format(sm_user))
    print('userid - {0}'.format(userid))

    if not sm_user and not userid:
        return HTTPFound(request.route_url('callback'))

    login_url = request.route_url('login')

    redirect_to = redirect_path(request)

    response = Response(json.dumps({'note': 'testing'}))
    return response


@view_config(route_name='callback')
def callback(request):

    log.debug('********* callback **********')
    print_requests(request)

    code = request.params.get('code')

    # userid, name = OAuth(code).get_user_info()
    userid ='lak'
    name = 'test'
    headers = remember(request, userid)
    login_url = request.route_url('login')
    print('login_url - ', login_url)

    response = HTTPSeeOther(location=login_url, headers=headers)
    response.set_cookie('name', name)
    response.set_cookie('userid', userid)

    return response


# @view_config(route_name='resource_1', permission='edit')
@view_config(route_name='resource_1')
def resource_1(request):
    print('u - ',unauthenticated_userid(request))
    print('a -', authenticated_userid(request))
    r = {'test': 'resource_1'}
    return Response(json.dumps(r))


@forbidden_view_config()
def resource_2(request):
    return Response('You are not allowed', status='403 Forbidden')

@view_config(route_name='mashup')
def mashup(request):
    print('mashup')

    r = {'Note': 'Undergoing test'}

    return Response(json.dumps(r))


def print_requests(request):
    pass
```

main.py

```
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from .security import groupfinder


def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                          root_factory='.resources.Root')
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')

    # Security policies
    authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(
        settings['tutorial.secret'], callback=groupfinder,
        hashalg='sha512')
    authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
    config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
    config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)

    config.add_route('login', '/')
    config.add_route('callback', '/login/oauth2/code')
    config.add_route('resource_1', '/resource_1')
    config.add_route('resource_2', '/resource_2')
    config.add_route('mashup', '/mashup.html')

    config.scan('.views')
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

security.py

```
import bcrypt


def hash_password(pw):
    pwhash = bcrypt.hashpw(pw.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
    return pwhash.decode('utf8')

def check_password(pw, hashed_pw):
    expected_hash = hashed_pw.encode('utf8')
    return bcrypt.checkpw(pw.encode('utf8'), expected_hash)


USERS = {'editor': hash_password('editor'),
         'viewer': hash_password('viewer')}
GROUPS = {'editor': ['group:editors'],
          'lak': ['group:editors']}


def groupfinder(userid, request):
    print('******** groupfinder ****', userid)
    print('group - ', GROUPS.get(userid, []))
    if userid in USERS:
        return GROUPS.get(userid, [])
```

resources.py

```
from pyramid.security import Allow, Everyone


class Root(object):
    __acl__ = [(Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
               (Allow, 'group:editors', 'edit')]

    def __init__(self, request):
        pass
```

Github URL:-

https://github.com/PREM1980/spa_authentication

Comment: Wait, do you expect authenticated_userid to return something within the same request? Normally the user submits the (un-authenticated) request with login and password, the server returns some headers (Set-Cookie); the browser then sends some cookies *on subsequent requests*; the server then sees the cookies and authenticated_userid returns something. Not within the same request-response cycle.

Comment: What is your question? What did you observe? What did you expect to happen? I'd suggest taking a look at the [tutorial for authentication step](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authentication.html) for a good example.

Comment: provided the comments below..I got that the authenticated request should be called in the next cycle but not sure why call back function is not being called.

Comment: How does your login view function look and how does your other view function look where the user is supposed to be authenticated? The former is supposed to return some response and the latter is supposed to be guarded by a permission. Please edit the question to include view function declarations.

Comment: I have added the info. When the user logs IN, he his redirected to a OAUTH page, once he provides consent, I get the userinfo and call the remember function. I expect the callback to be triggered when the login page is called again.

Comment: @sergey  - I have given the complete code above.

Comment: @StevePiercy I have given the code above, I expect the resource_1 url to be authenticated without any issues but it is forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `authenticated_userid` will not change in the same request in which you invoked `remember`. It is merely setting a cookie on the response object which the client will return on the NEXT request that indicates the auth status. In the current request, if you wish for `authenticated_userid` to change its value then you will have to implement your own `remember` or other mechanism for managing that - Pyramid does not do it by default in any of its authentication policies. The authentication policy API is simple and you can subclass/override it if you feel you need to change how that works.

Comment: The authenticated_userid that is called in route-resource_1, shows me None even I have visited the login page to remember the user.